# Maximum SATA drive size for Intel DP35DP?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I've got an Intel DP35DP motherboard on which I am trying to connect a WD Green 3TB drive.  But the BIOS (and Win 7) only recognizes it as 750+G.

I've tried to find the specs for the DP35DP to figure out which SATA controller (ICH9?  ICH10?  ICH11) it is running to hopefully see if it is a hardware limitation, or is there something wrong with the Drive?

Does anyone know if the DP35DP can support a 3TB drive natively, or do I need an additional SATA card?

Comment: What did you find?

Comment: Eh. I was wondering something similar, oddly enough. I wonder if we could genericise this a bit and turn it into a community FAQ?

Comment: @Xavierjazz - so far nothing new.  Still trying to figure this out.  Am very surprised that the BIOS only sees it as a 750G drive since I have an option in the BIOS to boot from UEFI drives.  So the BIOS should have support for it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the version of your firmware/BIOS. I believe the DP35DP was made both WITHOUT and WITH UEFI (support for drives bigger than 2TB).

I would as a first step flash the latest BIOS [from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=&ProductID=2782&ProdId=2782) and try again if you can see the full 3TB in the BIOS.

Comment: I checked and do have the latest BIOS already installed.  In fact, when I checked the BIOS options, I had the option to enable/disable boot UEFI drives (I have it turned off).  I still would have expected the BIOS to recognize it as a 3T drive.